# React Native CLI Custom Font Variation Specification on Windows vs macOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-cli

I'm currently working on a React Native project where I've integrated the "Inter" font from Google. The project is running on latest react native and I used react-native-asset to install the fonts. However, I've stumbled upon an intriguing discrepancy between Windows and macOS in terms of font rendering.

When using macOS, setting the fontFamily to "Inter" along with a fontWeight works seamlessly across both iOS and Android simulators:

```
<Text style={{ fontFamily: 'Inter', fontWeight: '600' }}>Hello World!</Text>
```

However, on Windows, the same configuration doesn't appear effective on Android. Specifically, I've observed that I must specify the exact font variation, like "Inter-Bold", for it to take effect. What's perplexing is that once I specify this exact font variation, the fontWeight no longer influences the font appearance—it seems that the fontFamily takes precedence in dictating font boldness.

Has anyone else experienced this anomaly? I'm keen to understand the underlying reasons, especially since such discrepancies could lead to inconsistent UI experiences across teams using different operating systems. Any insights or workarounds would be deeply appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the front name is different in Android and iOS. To check the name in Android you can use the following code.

Currently, you are working in react-native so please put this code in the MainActivity.java file.

```
 AssetManager assetManager = this.getAssets();
  try {
      for (String name : assetManager.list("fonts")) {
          Log.d("Test","Android front name "+name);
      }
  } catch (IOException error) {
      Log.e("Test", "Error in reading fonts.");
  }
```